# Renaming multiple files in python, identical names but different extensions

Tags: python

I'm trying to change the name of multiple files that all have identical names but various extensions, I get the impression there there is a simple streamlined method of doing this but I can't figure out how.

At present my code looks like this;

```
import os

def rename_test():
    os.rename ('cheddar.tasty.coor', 'newcheddar.vintage.coor')
    os.rename ('cheddar.tasty.txt', 'newcheddar.vintage.txt')
    os.rename ('cheddar.tasty.csv', 'newcheddar.vintage.csv')

rename_test()
```

Comment: Well, what exactly are your rules?  Do you want to rename those specific files only, or all files that might exist with the name 'cheddar.tasty.something'?  Does it have to be cheddar, or does anything .tasty. qualify?  Does anything before .tasty. get a new- stuck in front of it?

Comment: All files with cheddar.tasty, and it needs to be exactly cheddar.tasty. All files called cheddar.tasty get changed to newcheddar.vinatge.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
def rename(dirpath):
    whitelist = set('txt csv coor'.split())
    for fname in os.listdir(dirpath):
        name, cat, ext = os.path.basename(os.path.join(dirpath, fname)).rsplit(os.path.extsep,2)
        if ext not in whitelist:
            continue
        name = 'new' + name
        cat = 'vintage'
        newname = os.path.extsep.join([name, cat, ext])
        os.rename(os.path.join(dirpath, fname), os.path.join(dirpath, newname))
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use the `glob` module.  It really depends on what you want to improve.

```
for ext in ('*.coor', '*.txt', '*.csv'):
    for filename in glob.glob(ext):
        newname = filename.replace("cheddar.", "newcheddar.").replace(".tasty.", ".vintage.")
        os.rename(filename, newnew)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def rename_test():
    for ext in "coor txt csv".split():
        os.rename('cheddar.tasty.'+ext, 'newcheddar.vintage.'+ext)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `listdir` and `replace` - no regular expressions, no having to parse the filename twice.  Just one replace and an equality test:

```
import os
for old_filename in os.listdir('.'):
  new_filename = old_filename.replace('cheddar.tasty', 'newcheddar.vintage')
  if new_filename != old_filename:
     os.rename(old_filename, new_filename)
```